# How do I uniquely identify only network connections that are *not* VPN connections?

Tags: c#, network-programming

I'm trying to track all current network connections at run time, but I want to exclude VPN connections.

I need to be able to identify the network(s) being connected to, as well, so I'm using `NetworkListManagerClass()` to build a list of current connections:

```
var manager = new NetworkListManagerClass();
var connectedNetworks = manager.GetNetworks(NLM_ENUM_NETWORK.NLM_ENUM_NETWORK_CONNECTED).Cast<INetwork>();
```

I believe I can determine if a connection adapter is for a VPN by examining the `NetworkInterfaceType` of the `NetworkInterface` class:

```
NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().Where(n => n.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up).ToArray();

      foreach (NetworkInterface n in interfaces)
      {
          if (n.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Tunnel || n.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.PPP)
          {

          }
      }
```

However, it isn't enough for me to just know that an interface is or is not a VPN.  I need to be able to track details about the network that the non-VPN interfaces are **connected** to.

For example:

We'll call my work network "officenetwork".  We'll call my home network "homenetwork".

If I'm at work, I can see I'm connected to *officenetwork* by examining `NetworkListManagerClass` based off the `NLM_ENUM_NETWORK_CONNECTED` status.  My application should know that *officenetwork* is my current local network, and will store and reference settings specific to that network.

Similarly, if I'm at home, I should be able to see *homenetwork*, and store and reference a different set of settings specific to that network.

However, if I'm at home, and I use a VPN to connect to *officenetwork*, examining `NetworkListManagerClass` based off the `NLM_ENUM_NETWORK_CONNECTED` status will show both *homenetwork* and *officenetwork*.  Since the connection to *officenetwork* is a VPN, I need to ignore it, and only store and reference the settings for *homenetwork*.

This software will be for users who will connect to networks I know nothing about, so I cannot assume connection data for specific VPN's or networks.

How can I check current network connections and identify only networks that are **not** VPN connections, so I can store custom settings for that network?

Comment: Sorry about the incorrect tag; I indicated in the comments that I wasn't certain if it was appropriate.  If anyone could offer suggestions as to how to otherwise improve the question, I'd appreciate it, as I do not understand the reason for the downvote.

Comment: No worries about the tag - I just edited it out. Sorry for whoever downvoted it... wasn't me (an incorrect tag doesn't merit that.) If fact, I thought it was a pretty well-written question -- have an upvote! +1

Comment: network.GetNetworkConnections()...GetAdapterId() is a guid wich matches NetworkInterface.Id. Is this the missing link you're looking for?

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes!  That seems to be what I'm missing.  If you could post that as an answer, showing how to access the `GetAdapterId()` method, I'd be very happy to award the bounty!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an [INetwork](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370750.aspx) instance, you can get the list of connections ([INetworkConnections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370751.aspx) instances) using the [GetNetworkConnections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370785.aspx) method.

Then, using the [INetworkConnection::GetAdapterId method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370757.aspx), you can get a Guid that represent the adapter Id. The adapter Id in fact matches the [NetworkInterface.Id Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.id.aspx) (it's a string, but you can convert it to a Guid).

Here is a sample console app that dumps all network and their connections, and interface properties (type, name, etc.):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mgr = new NetworkListManager();
        foreach (INetwork network in mgr.GetNetworks(NLM_ENUM_NETWORK.NLM_ENUM_NETWORK_ALL))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Network: " + network.GetName());
            foreach (INetworkConnection conn in network.GetNetworkConnections())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Adapter Id:  " + conn.GetAdapterId());
                var ni = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(i => new Guid(i.Id) == conn.GetAdapterId());
                Console.WriteLine(" Interface: " + ni.Name);
                Console.WriteLine(" Type: " + ni.NetworkInterfaceType);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  This was exactly what I needed.